# How to disable assembly in Xcode's debugger window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

For some reason my Xcode debugger shows assembly code when debugging an iPhone app code. I'd like to see only Objective-C code, not assembly. This used to work OK but now something has changed. How to get back to "normal" debugging? Is there a setting in Xcode somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

@AlexR: To see the source code in Xcode 4.4, switch off *Show Disassembly When Debugging* over here: *Product* -> *Debug Workflow* -> *Show Disassembly When Debugging*

Comment: still getting assembler windows

Comment: I'm seeing disassembly despite the option being disabled.

Answer (score 4):

In Xcode 3.x: Run -> Debugger Display -> Source Only

Comment: See the newer answer from @0x5f3759df for an Xcode 4.x solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12387158/253056

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 8.2.1:

1. Click Menu item "Debug"
2. Select "Debug Workflow"
3. Click the "Always Show Disassembly", so that no checkmark appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem despite having unchecked the "Always show disassembly" option. Contacted Apple and they said

> "This is usally a permissions problem or an issue with dSYMs not being found by the debugger due to a bad .lldbinit file."