# Objective C - disable specific debug screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is it possible to disable, skip or ignore this type of screen in Xcode debug mode?

Image:
[image]

All I want to see is my Code,Classes,Variables etc.. without this type of screen (Not relevant to me)

Comment: It is not possible to see the implementation in case if implementation in Library or Framework.

Comment: Click step-out or continue to move to code area.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya - i just click on the "step into" button while running the debug and then this screen appear.

Comment: sometimes I need to click ten times "step out" or "continue" to move to area code. this is VERY annoying!

Comment: @user3481741: I agree, I think there is no such thing to do that. If you want to debug for some crash, then try finding it by stacktrace or use NSZombies

Answer (score 1):

**Check if you have disassembly deactivated**

[deactivate it in the XCode 4.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334797/how-to-disable-assembly-in-xcodes-debugger-window) [with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048625/why-is-my-xcode-jump-to-assembly-view-when-break-point-set):

```
Product -> Debug Workflow -> Show Disassembly When Debugging
```

And in XCode 5.X via:

```
Debug > Debug Workflow > Show Disassembly when debugging.
```

**Filter the debug info**

Another tactic to avoid steps into assembly is filtering the stack trace to your source code in a button at the Debug Navigator.

When you are debugging, open the debug navigator (the one that shows the threads) and press in the left bottom corner. ([Apple documentation shows more about that](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/Xcode4TransitionGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#Examine%20Threads%20and%20Stacks).). Note that you need to be stopped in a breakpoint.

[image]

Comment: By default it is deactivated only. And once you activate then the first breakpoint will take you to this assembly page.

Comment: So true. Dunno why I had this activated :p. Going to delete it :)

Comment: Well, that might help, I don't know a permanent-easy solution for that issue though. Also I have left that tip to deactivate since I have seen several SO questions that had that activated :)